# accept() doesn't block the program execution

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm starting to program network programs in asm (NASM) and technically, the accept function block the program (passive socket). Well, in my program I execute the program and the program finish. I've tested setting the backlog to 1 (listen function), but it's not the problem... What happen?

```
BITS 32

section .text
global _start
_start:
; Create the socket file descriptor
; int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);

mov eax, 102  ; __NR_socketcall
mov ebx, 1    ; socketcall type (socket)

; socket parameters
push 0  ; IPPROTO_TCP
push 1  ; SOCK_STREAM
push 2  ; AF_INET

int 0x80  ; socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)

mov edx, eax  ; edx = socketfd


; Bind the socket with an address type
; int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);

mov eax, 102  ; __NR_socketcall
mov ebx, 2    ; socketcall type (bind)

; build the sockaddr_in struct
push 0            ; INADDR_ANY
push WORD 0x0457  ; port 1111
push WORD 2       ; AF_INET
mov ecx, esp      ; struct ptr

; bind parameters
push 16   ; sockaddr struct size = sizeof(struct sockaddr) = 16
push ecx  ; sockaddr_in struct ptr
push edx  ; socket fd

int 0x80  ; bind(sockfd, {AF_INET, 11111, INADDR_ANY}, 16)


; Prepare to listen the incoming connection (passive socket)
; int listen(int sockfd, int backlog);

mov eax, 102  ; __NR_socketcall
mov ebx, 4    ; socketcall type (listen)

; listen parameters
push 0    ; nº connections in the waiting queue (0 = accept and we haven't queue)
push edx  ; socket fd

int 0x80  ; listen(sockfd, 0);


; Accept the incoming connection
; int accept(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);

mov eax, 102  ; __NR_socketcall
mov ebx, 5    ; socketcall type (accept)

; accept parameters
push 0
push 0
push edx  ; socket fd

int 0x80  ; accept(sockfd, NULL, NULL)

; Exit
; int exit(int status)

mov eax, 1 ; __NR_exit
mov ebx, 0 ; exit code

int 0x80
```

Comment: Doesn't linux use the `%ebx`, `%ecx` and `%edx` registers for the first, second and third arguments when you're calling `int 0x80`?

Comment: What? I'm using NASM (I put as tag), so it's ebx instead of %ebx and all movs, pushs, etc. are commented.

Comment: yeah, I'm using a different register format; not that it matters. The socketcall call **always** takes only two parameters - the socketcall type and a pointer to a user address containing the remainder of the parameters. It's a royal pain to hand-code. You have absolutely no error handing in your code, which means that any failure in any call wouldn't be detected, causing the fallthrough of the accept call.

Comment: Then you suggest my program is well done, that the problem is in my PC and I must handle the errors to know "some stuff", no? Must I check in ALL socketcall type (after execute int 0x80) if eax (I've not found information about to handle socketcall) is -1?

Comment: I think you need to `mov ecx, esp` more often (as Petesh suggests). `ecx` needs to point to your structure (on the stack).

Comment: No, your program is missing the needed `mov ecx, esp` immediately prior to the invocation of the `int 0x80` which is needed to get the correct arguments to `socketcall`. You handle errors to determine what went wrong (you could use `strace` to prevent yourself from having to compile the checks in for debugging purposes); you have to `htons()` the number of the port, otherwise it binds to one that you don't expect. It's simply good programming practice to *check your return codes* after making any API call if a return code is provided

Comment: When checking for errors, `eax` will be <0, not -1 exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're missing a `mov ecx, esp` after the last push for each of your argument pushes, as well as `htons`'ing the port number. A fixed version of you code should look like:

```
BITS 32

section .text
global _start
_start:
; Create the socket file descriptor
; int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);

mov eax, 102  ; __NR_socketcall
mov ebx, 1    ; socketcall type (socket)

; socket parameters
push 6  ; IPPROTO_TCP
push 1  ; SOCK_STREAM
push 2  ; AF_INET
mov ecx, esp ; <<== uargs* in ecx

int 0x80  ; socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)

mov edx, eax  ; edx = socketfd


; Bind the socket with an address type
; int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);

mov eax, 102  ; __NR_socketcall
mov ebx, 2    ; socketcall type (bind)

; build the sockaddr_in struct
push 0            ; INADDR_ANY
push WORD 0x5704  ; port 1111 == htons(1111)
push WORD 2       ; AF_INET
mov ecx, esp      ; struct ptr

; bind parameters
push 16   ; sockaddr struct size = sizeof(struct sockaddr) = 16
push ecx  ; sockaddr_in struct ptr
push edx  ; socket fd
mov ecx, esp      ; <<== uargs* in ecx

int 0x80  ; bind(sockfd, {AF_INET, 11111, INADDR_ANY}, 16)


; Prepare to listen the incoming connection (passive socket)
; int listen(int sockfd, int backlog);

mov eax, 102  ; __NR_socketcall
mov ebx, 4    ; socketcall type (listen)

; listen parameters
push 0    ; nº connections in the waiting queue (0 = accept and we haven't queue)
push edx  ; socket fd
mov ecx, esp      ; <<== uargs* in ecx

int 0x80  ; listen(sockfd, 0);


; Accept the incoming connection
; int accept(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);

mov eax, 102  ; __NR_socketcall
mov ebx, 5    ; socketcall type (accept)

; accept parameters
push 0
push 0
push edx  ; socket fd
mov ecx, esp      ; struct ptr

int 0x80  ; accept(sockfd, NULL, NULL)

; Exit
; int exit(int status)

mov eax, 1 ; __NR_exit
mov ebx, 0 ; exit code

int 0x80
```

In this case it would have been important that you did an `strace` on your program to verify that you were seeing the correct parameters being processed in the system call.

If we `strace` your original program we get:

```
socket(PF_UNSPEC, 0, 0)                 = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
bind(1459879938, NULL, 2)               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
listen(1459879938, 0)                   = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
accept(1459879938, 0, 0x2)              = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
```

all of which looks like things went very badly.

If you look at the source for `compat_sys_socketcall` it shows:

```
asmlinkage long compat_sys_socketcall(int call, u32 __user *args)
```

which means EBX is the call and ECX points to the remainder of the arguments.

Comment: Perfect! I've tested the strace, but when do you get the compat_syscall_socketcall? If I search "compat_syscall_socketcall" in Google only appears this page...